# How to edit the default instrument of an AUGraph?

Tags: iphone, c, ios, audio, core-audio

I'm working with the MusicPlayer API. I understand that when you load in a .mid as a sequence, the API creates a default AUGraph for you that includes an AUSampler. This AUSampler uses a simple sine-wave based instrument to synthesize the notes in the .mid

My question is, how does one change the default instrument in the AUSampler? I understand that you can use SoundFont2 files (.sf2) and add them using the AudioUnitSetProperty method. But, how does one access this default AUGraph? Do you have to open the graph before you can edit the AudioUnit or is opening a graph only for editing connections between nodes?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at the [Audiograph](http://zerokidz.com/audiograph/Home.html) example. It doesn't use soundFonts but should give you an idea of how to set up a graph.

When I use the MusicPlayer I always generate the midi note data from code/GUI and create the AUGraph (with a mixer) from scratch. There are ways to derive/extract the default generated AUGraph & AUSampler resulting from loading a midi file (example code below) but I never had success setting a new soundFont this way. On the other hand, creating the AUGraph from scratch and then loading an .sf2 file works great.

```
AUGraph graph;
result =  MusicSequenceGetAUGraph (sequence, &graph);

MusicTrack firstTrack;
result =  MusicSequenceGetIndTrack (sequence, 0, &firstTrack);

AUNode myNode;
result = MusicTrackGetDestNode(firstTrack,&myNode);

AudioUnit mySamplerUnit;
result = AUGraphNodeInfo(graph, myNode, 0, &mySamplerUnit);
```

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much what I ended up doing. But instead of editing the existing AUGraph that gets generated, I copied it into a new one and edited the properties of the AUSampler before I put it in. Worked like a charm :)

Comment: Are you using (planning to use) sound samples or the sf2/DLS method?

Comment: Currently, I am using an SF2 but I'm running into a problem. The app runs great on the simulator but it crashes when I try to load the view that does the playback. I believe, from looking at the console, that its crashing due to low memory. I think the problem is that my SF2 file is 72MB. That seems like its going to be too large for an iPad. Do you know of any piano SF2's that are smallish? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Yup, switched it back to the lightweight sine-based tone generator and it worked fine. So, I need a more lightweight solution...

Comment: There are loads of sf2 files of varying quality here:http://hammersound.net/cgi-bin/soundlink.pl  - One good thing I've discovered is that multiple AUSamplers using the same sf2 use the same sound resources so memory is optimized. Some sf2 have loads of presets that sound quite different so reusing the same sf2 is an option and still have a range of instruments.

Comment: Thanks! I found a great one :)

Answer (score 4):

I've written a tutorial on this but [here](http://www.deluge.co/?q=midi-driven-animation-core-audio-objective-c) but here's an outline of the process:

Function to load a Sound Font file (taken from the Apple documentation):

```
    -(OSStatus) loadFromDLSOrSoundFont: (NSURL *)bankURL withPatch: (int)presetNumber {

OSStatus result = noErr;

// fill out a bank preset data structure
AUSamplerBankPresetData bpdata;
bpdata.bankURL  = (__bridge CFURLRef) bankURL;
bpdata.bankMSB  = kAUSampler_DefaultMelodicBankMSB;
bpdata.bankLSB  = kAUSampler_DefaultBankLSB;
bpdata.presetID = (UInt8) presetNumber;

// set the kAUSamplerProperty_LoadPresetFromBank property
result = AudioUnitSetProperty([pointer to your AUSampler node here],
                          kAUSamplerProperty_LoadPresetFromBank,
                          kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                          0,
                          &bpdata,
                          sizeof(bpdata));

// check for errors
NSCAssert (result == noErr,
       @"Unable to set the preset property on the Sampler. Error code:%d '%.4s'",
       (int) result,
       (const char *)&result);

return result; }
```

Then you need to load the Sound Font from your Resources folder:

```
NSURL *presetURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Name of sound font" ofType:@"sf2"]];

// Initialise the sound font
[self loadFromDLSOrSoundFont: (NSURL *)presetURL withPatch: (int)10];
```

Hope this helps!